# How to merge 2 searches in Angular Heroes tutorial?

Tags: angular, merge, get, rxjs, reactivex

I am trying to merge 2 HTTP get searches in Angular/TypeScript, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

The situation is illustrated using the Angular 2 / 4 Tour of Heroes tutorial, which uses an Observable to search heroes for by"name" value (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#add-the-ability-to-search-by-name).  The code in hero-search.service.ts is as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http }       from '@angular/http';

import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Hero }           from './hero';

@Injectable()
export class HeroSearchService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  search(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http
               .get(`api/heroes/?name=${term}`)
               .map(response => response.json().data as Hero[]);
  }
}
```

I need to do the equivalent of adding a second string value for "synonym" to the Hero class:

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  synonym: string;
}
```

and add a synonym to each Hero:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const heroes = [
      { id: 0,  name: 'Zero', synonym: 'little' },
      { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice', synonym: 'pleasant' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco', synonym: 'sleep' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto', synonym: 'loud' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas', synonym: 'vegetable' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta', synonym: 'color' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan', synonym: 'hose' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama', synonym: 'motor' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ', synonym: 'smart' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma', synonym: 'volcanic' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado', synonym: 'wind' }
    ];
    return {heroes};
  }
}
```

I can then search in hero-search.service.ts by synonym by substituting:

```
       .get(`api/heroes/?synonym=${term}`)
```

My question is how to search for both name and synonym and return matches with either name or synonym.

From the ReactiveX documentation it seems like the answer is to use the Merge operator: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html.  However, I'm having trouble getting this to work.  I've tried various ways of using merge, including the following new version of the hero-search.service.ts code above:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http }       from '@angular/http';

import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';

import { Hero }           from './hero';

@Injectable()
export class HeroSearchService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  search(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
    const nameResults = this.http.get(`api/heroes/?name=${term}`);
    const synonymResults = this.http.get(`api/heroes/?synonym=${term}`);    
    nameResults.merge(synonymResults);
    return nameResults.map(response => response.json().data as Hero[]);
  }
}
```

The not-working-properly code is at https://plnkr.co/edit/4mrL5ReQCSvuzOODixJU?p=preview.

I don't see any evidence that the merge succeeded, and nameResults give only names, not synonyms. No error messages appear.

The RxJS code at http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html uses code of the form

```
const mergedResults = Rx.Observable.merge(nameResults, synonymResults);
```

but when I try such code I get an error flagged:

> Cannot find name 'Rx'

So my questions are:

How can one use RxJS merge here?

Is there some other approach using RxJS that is more suitable?

Is there some other approach at the level of the Hero class that will work such as computing namePlusSynonym without having to add namePlusSynonym to each line in the Hero array?

ADDENDUM: following suggestions here and code at http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-merge I created a new version of hero-search.service.ts with console outputs.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';

import { Hero } from './hero';

@Injectable()
export class HeroSearchService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  search(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
    const nameResults = this.http.get(`api/heroes/?name=${term}`);
    nameResults.subscribe(nameData => console.log('nameData', nameData));
    const synonymResults = this.http.get(`api/heroes/?synonym=${term}`);
    synonymResults.subscribe(synonymData => console.log('synonymData', synonymData));
    const combinedResults = nameResults.merge(synonymResults);
    combinedResults.subscribe(combinedData => console.log('combinedData', combinedData));
    return combinedResults.map(response => response.json().data as Hero[]);
  }
}
```

But it only displays synonymResults, not nameResults.  Both nameResults and synonymResults look OK to me in the console output, but combinedResults has only data and the url for synonym results and seems unaffected by the merge method.

I also tried with concat, with similar results.

It seems that I'm not combining at the right stage, but combining at a different stage gives the same result, only showing synonyms:

```
  search(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
    const nameResults = this.http.get(`api/heroes/?name=${term}`).map(response => response.json().data as Hero[]);
    nameResults.subscribe(nameData => console.log('nameData', nameData));
    const synonymResults = this.http.get(`api/heroes/?synonym=${term}`).map(response => response.json().data as Hero[]);
    synonymResults.subscribe(synonymData => console.log('synonymData', synonymData));
    const combinedResults = nameResults.merge(synonymResults);
    combinedResults.subscribe(combinedData => console.log('combinedData', combinedData));
    return combinedResults;
  }
```

Comment: It seems a bit unusual to use two HTTP requests and then merge them on the client side.  Normally I'd expect to see something like `api/heroes?synonym=${synonym}&name=${name}`.  However, I think one thing you are missing is `nameResults = nameResults.merge(synonymResults);`  You are ignoring the return from merge which is the merged observable.

Comment: Or better yet, `let combinedResults = nameResults.merge(synonymResults)` and then return `combinedResults.map(...)`

Comment: Changing the last two lines to: `const combinedResults = nameResults.merge(synonymResults);
    return combinedResults.map(response => response.json().data as Hero[]);` results in synonym working but not name.

Comment: It should emit twice, once for each HTTP call.  Is it possible your second result is overwriting your first?  If you want to combine both results into a single list you will need something like...`let combinedResults = nameResults.merge(synonymResults).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));`

Comment: The suggested line is flagged as an error in the IDE: Property 'concat' does not exist on type 'Response'.  I'm unfamiliar with these operations so I'm having difficulty troubleshooting.

Comment: Sorry, `concat` is an array method to combine two arrays.  The `reduce` will have to come after the `map`.

Comment: Pace: there isn't enough space in the comments for me to understand what you mean.  Could you try posting this as an answer?  Also, I expanded my original post with an addendum to improve the code, but I still haven't gotten it to work.

Answer (score 0):

To get the merge operator to work, you need to import Observable and merge from rxjs, just as it is in the plunker:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';
```

> How can one use RxJS merge here?

I think your main misunderstanding here is that calling `merge()` on an observable returns a *new merged observable*. As rxjs functions are [pure](https://www.sitepoint.com/functional-programming-pure-functions/), calling it here does not mutate `namedResults`

```js
nameResults.merge(synonymResults);
```

Instead, you should capture the results in a new constant

```js
const combinedResults = nameResults.merge(synonymResults);
return combinedResults;
```

> Is there some other approach using RxJS that is more suitable?

This is how I solved the problem ([plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/IRe1WJ46UOxIA2x3ACeW?p=preview)) to get it to work without changing the existing angular component, only changing the `hero-search.service.ts`. You could make this look much nicer by chaining operators together, but I think that seeing helpful variables names with types at each stage is very helpful for learning. You could put an intermediate `subscribe()` & `console.log()` on any of the observables for testing to see what the value actually looks like.

```js
search(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
  // get the response observable from requesting the backend      
  const nameResults: Response = this.http.get(`api/heroes/?name=${term}`);
  // boil that response down to just the data array we care about
  const nameResultsArr: Observable<Hero[]> = nameResults.map(res => res.json().data);
  // do the same for the synonym request
  const synonymResults: Response = this.http.get(`api/heroes/?synonym=${term}`);
  const synonymResultsArr: Observable<Hero[]> = synonymResults.map(res => res.json().data);

  // combine the two observable arrays into a stream of arrays
  const combinedHeroListObservables: Observable<Hero[]> =
    nameResultsArr.merge(synonymResultsArr);
  // concat the observable arrays onto each other
  const concatenatedArrays: Observable<Hero[]> =
    combinedHeroListObservables.reduce((accumulator, current) => accumulator.concat(current));

  // return the combined array
  return concatenatedArrays;
}
```

> but when I try such code I get an error flagged:
>   `Cannot find name 'Rx'`

If you don't care about needlessly importing things you're not using, you can get this to work with

```js
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

But, it is good practice to only import the operators/types that you need as seen in the plunker example.

PS: Like some said in the comments, it would be good to have a rest route that returned both of the results combined already so the client doesn't have to make two round trips to the server. But, you can't really do this because you are using the Angular team's example.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  This does indeed run in Plunker, but when I put it into VSCode I get 8 errors and the program won't start.  
nameResults is flagged with Type 'Observable<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Response'.  Property 'body' is missing in type 'Observable<Response>'. 
map is flagged with Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Response'.          const combinedHeroListObservables: Observable<Observable<Hero[]>[]> = nameResultsArr.merge(synonymResultsArr);

Comment: And combinedHeroListObservables is flagged with Type 'Observable<Hero[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Observable<Hero[]>[]>'.
  Type 'Hero[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Hero[]>[]'.
    Type 'Hero' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Hero[]>'.
      Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Hero'.

Comment: And I don't know if the import 'rxjs/add/observable/from'; is needed or left over from something else.

Comment: What is your package.json? When I download from the plunker I don't get one. It also looks like this project dates before angular switched to webpack and is still using systemjs..

Comment: I updated the answer/plunker with the correct types and a more simple solution. `Observable.from()` was left over from me hard-coding observable arrays in my test code `const nameResultsArr: Observable<Hero[]> = Observable.of([{id: 1, name: 'Hero 1', synonym: 'Other Name 1'}]);`

Comment: I don't see anything new in the Plunker.  Can you post the code in another Plunker or here?

Comment: both the plunker linked in the answer and the answer code have been updated (full link here https://plnkr.co/edit/IRe1WJ46UOxIA2x3ACeW?p=preview)

Comment: This is close to working.  I get 2 basic errors, one each for the declarations of nameResults and synonymResults.  The message for nameResults is `Type 'Observable<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Response'.`  But changing Response to Observable<Response> I get the message `Type 'Observable<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Response>'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.`.  
Odd.
Deleting the word Response gives code that works.

So if you could delete Response I can mark this as the answer, though it would be great to add the correct type.

Comment: I found one other problem.  If a search sequence is in both the name and the synonym, it appears twice in the list.  For example, when searching for the letter d Tornado appears twice because its synonym is wind.

Comment: Adding combinedHeroListObservables.subscribe(combinedData => console.log('combinedData', combinedData)); shows that for each input change there are two different combinedHeroListObservables generated for the merge.  I had imagined that the whole point of the "merge" was to create one.   I would have imagined that "merge" would be all that was needed and there would be no need for "concat", though I can see a need to use "reduce" to get rid of the duplication.  This RxJS stuff is not very intuitive or at least I haven't found relevant code examples.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get the plunker running at all :/ there is something wrong with the SystemJS configuration, which I'm no expert at fixing. But, to make sure your list of heroes is unique, you can use the `distinct()` RxJS operator http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html

You might need to add a comparator function on the Hero's name.

As for what `merge()` actually does, it combines the data streams into 1 observable you can `subscribe()` to. This means that the two requests can complete and you would get two different notifications from different obs in one place

Comment: Hey Mickey, I would check out this tutorial. This may allow you to implement a more simple solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b59tcUwfpWU